# Docker EXPOSE using run-time environment variables

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile sets some defaults for environment variables, then later exposes two ports that should be the provided environment variables:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-stretch

[ ... ]

ENV MY_SERVICE_PORT 8080
ENV MY_SERVICE_PORT_RPC 50051

[ ... ]

EXPOSE ${MY_SERVICE_PORT}
EXPOSE ${MY_SERVICE_PORT_RPC}
```

My application inside the container reads the environment variable correctly when starting the container. If I run my image using:

```
docker run -e "MY_SERVICE_PORT=80" -d -t image_tag
```

Then I use `docker ps`:

```
0fb14e12d43d    image_tag    "/bin/sh -c 'python3…"   8080/tcp, 50051/tcp
```

As you can see, `EXPOSE` used the build-time environment variables (defaulting to 8080 and 50051). If I execute `set` inside the container terminal, I get:

```
MY_SERVICE_PORT=80
MY_SERVICE_PORT_RPC=50051
```

How can I make sure `EXPOSE` is only set to a run-time environment variable? Is it possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are not sure what your exposed ports will be then don't set them in the dockerfile. Just use `--expose` with `docker run` to specify ports at run time along with environment variable for details:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

Comment: Makes sense. Then again, I wanted to use env variables here so the EXPOSE and the inner application have the same port. I guess I will have to use a script to run the `docker run` command with the same env variable.

Comment: Script is a good idea. Normally if you manage your containers using a docker compose, kubernetes etc they allowing configuring these options so you should be fine.

Answer (score 35):

A little late but you could also use build args and change your code to:

```
FROM python:3.6.5-stretch

[ ... ]

ARG MY_SERVICE_PORT=8080
ARG MY_SERVICE_PORT_RPC=50051
# 8080 and 50051 would be the defaults

[ ... ]
# Still functions like environment variables :)
EXPOSE ${MY_SERVICE_PORT}
EXPOSE ${MY_SERVICE_PORT_RPC}
```

Then you can build with `docker build --build-arg MY_SERVICE_PORT=80 -t image_tag`
before you run. 
This way you could have your containerized application and your container running with the same ports without getting too complex.