Building Docker image for Golem Shiny App fails due to own golem package
I am trying to create a Dockerfile for a Golem Shiny app, using the golem::add_dockerfile_with_renv function. I am new to using Docker and I can't get the image to build because I do not understand how to handle the integration of my own Golem package.
The app is working when started in the normal fashion (app.R => pkgload::load_all; MyPackage::run_app()).
The app is currently using renv although I would like to in the future just install the newest packages available in a given rocker image. My Golem R package, let's call it MyPackage, is snapshotted into renv.lock as
"MyPackage": {
  "Package": "MyPackage",
  "Version": "0.0.0.9000",
  "Source": "Local",
  "RemoteType": "local",
  "RemoteUrl": "/home/myuser/repos/mypackage",
  "Requirements": [
    "DBI",
    "R",
    "RPostgres",
    "blastula",
    "config",
    "dplyr",
    "glue",
    "golem",
    "magrittr",
    "pins",
    "pkgload",
    "plotly",
    "rlang",
    "scales",
    "sf",
    "shiny",
    "shiny.i18n",
    "shinyWidgets",
    "shinyalert",
    "shinycssloaders",
    "shinyhelper",
    "shinyjs"
  ],
  "Hash": "f03..."

When I run
golem::add_dockerfile_with_renv(lockfile = "./renv.lock", output_dir = "deploy", from = "rocker/verse")
it creates a the following files in subdir deploy
Dockerfile, Dockerfile_base, README, renv.lock, myPackage_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz
When I follow the instructions in README to run
sudo docker build -f Dockerfile_base --progress=plain -t myPackage_base .
it fails with
#12 36.80 - Downloading MyPackage from Repository ...                ERROR [error code 22]
#12 37.02 Warning: failed to find source for 'MyPackage 0.0.0.9000' in package repositories
#12 37.02 Warning: error downloading 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/MyPackage/MyPackage_0.0.0.9000.tar.gz' [error code 22]
#12 37.02 Error: failed to retrieve package 'MyPackage@0.0.0.9000'

MyPackage is clearly marked as "Source: Local" in renv.lock and the project is in a consistent state according to renv::status().
I assume that I have two options:

exclude MyPackage from renv.lock (renv::snapshot(exclude = "MyPackage")), copy the MyPackage dir into Docker and build it there using remotes::install_local(".") or
try to adjust the RemoteUrl in renv.lock in a way that golem::add_dockerfile_with_renv() automatically understands/handles properly.

I've tried both ways (with multiple variations) but can't get anything to work.
Could anyone please point me to a solution? How do you handle your Golem package with renv? Do you snapshot it or exclude it? How do you install it inside the image? Thank you for your help in advance!
Dockerfile_base:
FROM rocker/verse:4.1.3
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y  libpq-dev make libicu-dev libxml2-dev pandoc libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev git libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libfribidi-dev libharfbuzz-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev zlib1g-dev libssh2-1-dev libgdal-dev gdal-bin libgeos-dev libproj-dev libsqlite3-dev libudunits2-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/R/etc/ /usr/lib/R/etc/
RUN echo "options(renv.config.pak.enabled = FALSE, repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/'), download.file.method = 'libcurl', Ncpus = 4)" | tee /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site | tee /usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN R -e 'remotes::install_version("renv", version = "1.0.7")'
COPY renv.lock renv.lock
RUN R -e 'renv::restore()'

I've tried various workarounds.

Excluding MyPackage from renv.lock (renv::snapshot(exclude="MyPackage")), copying it into Docker image and install_local

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN R -e "remotes::install_local('/app')"

Outcome:

#12 0.466 > remotes::install_local('/app')
#12 0.478 Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from local:


Like 1 but with COPY /home/myuser/repos/mypackage/ /app
Outcome:

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref cb58...::yqll2...: "/home/myuser/repos/mypackage": not found

(directory exists and is the same as in renv.lock before exclusion)

Using golem::add_dockerfile() instead
Dockerfile then looks like this:

FROM rocker/verse:4.1.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  gdal-bin libcurl4-openssl-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libicu-dev libpq-dev libproj-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libudunits2-dev libxml2-dev make pandoc zlib1g-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/R/etc/ /usr/lib/R/etc/
RUN echo "options(repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/'), download.file.method = 'libcurl', Ncpus = 4)" | tee /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site | tee /usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN Rscript -e 'remotes::install_version("magrittr",upgrade="never", version = "2.0.3")'
[...]
RUN mkdir /build_zone
ADD . /build_zone
WORKDIR /build_zone
RUN R -e 'install.packages("remotes");remotes::install_local(path = ".", upgrade="never")'
RUN rm -rf /build_zone
EXPOSE 80
CMD R -e "options('shiny.port'=80,shiny.host='0.0.0.0');MyPackage::run_app()"

Outcome:
Could not copy /build_zone to /tmp/Rtmp...
The image still builds in this case and when I go into the docker container sudo docker run -it ... /bin/bash I cannot see any issues like directory permissions or disk space that prevent copying to /tmp. Manually copying inside the container does work as well. Probably unrelated but I have set my own tmp dir to an external drive like this
TMPDIR=/mnt/encrypted_disk/tmp_dir/ inside .Renviron due to disk space issue on /.
Yes, the encrypted_disk is decrypted before using R/Docker.

I have seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72017488/18714313 but I don't think it applies to my issue.


On workaround 1, WORKDIR /app changes the working directory to /app but you then specify /app again in install.local() meaning it is trying to install from /app/app. Remove the WORKDIR and try again?

@smartse That was indeed the issue/solution. Thank you very much! I still have other issues in the build process but the image is being built and the Golem shiny app is running from inside the container.

What worked for me is removing the package not only from renv snapshot but from the installed libraries, do something like

Deactivate renv
remove MyPackage from your R lib by running remove.packages('MyPackage')
Re-activate renv and take a new snapshot, making sure MyPackage isn't in the lock file

Now you can add_dockerfile_with_renv and do the rest.
